# Select com operador IN em coluna do tipo array no Postgres

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Boa noite pessoal!

Eu tenho uma coluna (ids_autores) que é um array de inteiros em uma tabela do Postgres. Eu to tentando fazer um select com o operador IN nessa coluna, porém está dando erro. To tentando fazer a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT 
titulo,
ids_autores
FROM tb_livros 
WHERE ids_autores IN (10,15)
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer uma consulta desse tipo?

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que sua tabela seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_livros
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  titulo TEXT,
  ids_autores INT[]
);
```

Contendo os seguintes dados:

```
INSERT INTO tb_livros ( titulo, ids_autores ) VALUES ( 'Fooz', ARRAY[5] );
INSERT INTO tb_livros ( titulo, ids_autores ) VALUES ( 'Foo', ARRAY[10] );
INSERT INTO tb_livros ( titulo, ids_autores ) VALUES ( 'Bar', ARRAY[15] );
INSERT INTO tb_livros ( titulo, ids_autores ) VALUES ( 'FooBar', ARRAY[10,15,20] );
INSERT INTO tb_livros ( titulo, ids_autores ) VALUES ( 'Baz', ARRAY[10,20,30] );
```

Como o campo `ids_autores` se trata de um tipo `ARRAY`, você deve usar o operador [`@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html) para verificar se sua lista de ids **contém** os ids que você deseja filtrar.

**Solução 1:** Recupera todos os livros que tenham como autores os identificadores `10` **e** `15`:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  titulo,
  ids_autores
FROM
  tb_livros 
WHERE
  ids_autores @> ARRAY[10,15];
```

Saída:

```
| id | titulo | ids_autores |
|----|--------|-------------|
|  4 | FooBar |    10,15,20 |
```

**Solução 2:** Recupera todos os livros que tenham os autores com os identificadores `10` **ou** `15`:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  titulo,
  ids_autores
FROM
  tb_livros 
WHERE
  ids_autores @> ARRAY[10] OR
  ids_autores @> ARRAY[15];
```

Saída:

```
| id | titulo | ids_autores |
|----|--------|-------------|
|  2 |    Foo |          10 |
|  3 |    Bar |          15 |
|  4 | FooBar |    10,15,20 |
|  5 |    Baz |    10,20,30 |
```

Veja funcionando no [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c3c1a/2)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o operador de arrays adequado, no caso o OVERLAPS:

```
SELECT titulo, ids_autores
    FROM tb_livros 
    WHERE ids_autores && ARRAY[10,15];
```

Se um dos elementos, 10 ou 15, existir no array.